# View question's "history" as animated playback

Tags: feature-request, questions, revisions-list, javascript

While I was searching for the "history" button of the post I had thought it would be cool to have the history of the whole question sorted by time.

For my understanding the evolution of a question it's related to those elements:

- question
- answers
- comments
- various edits
- accepted answer
- up/down votes

Since everything looks like versioned on the server (or at least a timestamp on it) would be possible to extract and sort all the components involved by time.

In order to have a very clear understanding of the evolution of the question, it would be nice to see the question composing on the page with a little delay (like a slideshow).
The idea would be to start just with the first version of the question and automatically scrolling up and down the page smoothly to before "inject" the new element.
Additionally could be added somewhere (floating bar ?) some buttons  to control the workflow (play/pause, back, forward).

my 2 cents :)

Comment: This seems entirely frivolous and not much more *useful* than what we already have. I'm not sure it's worth the time to implement.

Comment: you mean the timeline ? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/180981/timeline

Answer (score 2):

We have a timeline in which everything is included. I don't think it's worth the developer effort to implement this.

Also, think of this from a UX point of view. For almost every question you have to scroll down to see everything. Comments are hidden behind a link most of the time. How are you going to display everything in an animation, without losing information (because it looks like that's what you want)?

Comment: well, the idea would be (for example) to add the html related to a comment and then scroll the document to that point. Few seconds later repeat it with the next element.

Comment: @Cesar you want to get dizzy?

Comment: dizzy ? way ? if you implement a smooth page scroll it's very nice :)

Comment: @Cesar then it would take way too long.

Comment: that's why I thought about adding some additional buttons for controlling the flow ;)

Comment: @Cesar you see how complicated this becomes, both from a developers as a UX point of view? Your feature-request perhaps can be fun/useful sometimes, but it's just not worth the effort.